# Liferay 7 Role/ Permission issue : You do not have the roles required to access this portlet

Tags: spring, liferay, hook, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I created a PortletMVC in Liferay 7.3.0 it is deployed successfully in Tomcat 9 but when I drag it in the portal, I cannot see it and the message displayed is the following :

```
" You do not have the roles required to access this portlet.
"
```

[Image]

[image]

I checked the permission of the page it was public and the guest can view it,

[image]

Can anyone please help if there is something wrong thanks.
This is the classController:

```
@Component(
    immediate = true, 
    property = {
            "path=/login/login",
            "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=guest,power-user,user",
    },
    service = StrutsPortletAction.class
)
public class BladePortletAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {

    @Override
    public void processAction(
            StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
            PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws Exception {....}
```

the console display :

```
[SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:235] Invalid portlet ID /app_WAR_app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says:

```
[SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:235] Invalid portlet ID /app_WAR_app
```

You didn't attach a unique **ID** to your portlet yet, you should know that in Liferay, every portlet have a unique ID (KEY) using the property **`javax.portlet.name`**

Take this code as an example:

```
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
                "javax.portlet.name=com_fr_bladeExamplePortlet"
        },
        properties = "OSGI-INF/portlet.properties",
        service = Portlet.class
)
public class SearchPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
}
```

If you are using Liferay DXP, I recommend you to work with **MVCPortlet**, it's  simple, light, effective and ease of use.

[Liferay MVC Porlet](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018159451-Liferay-MVC-Portlet)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see that you are using:
BaseStrutsPortletAction  but it is not the same as MVCPortlet.
Please note that since Liferay 7.0, the BaseStrutsPortletAction mechanism no longer applies for most portlets because Liferay no longer use Struts Actions, but uses Liferay MVCCommands instead, see:

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029005292-Upgrading-Struts-Action-Hooks
https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/96576834

I recommend using Liferay Developer Studio, that way you can see which classes/methods are available during portlet development.

In case you need further assistance, I am happy to help, just please send more detailed information like: what you would like to achieve, and more detailed steps like:

1. Downloaded the Liferay Portal from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/7.3.0%20GA1/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.3.0-ga1-20200127150653953.tar.gz/download
2. Executed:
   blade update
   mkdir lr_workspace
   blade init
3. Edited: gradle.properties and ensured it contains Liferay 7.3.0 specific values:
   liferay.version.default=7.3
   profile.name=gradle
   liferay.workspace.bundle.url=https://releases-cdn.liferay.com/portal/7.3.0-ga1/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.3.0-ga1-20200127150653953.tar.gz
   app.server.tomcat.version=9.0.33
   liferay.workspace.target.platform.version=7.3.0
   target.platform.index.sources=false
4. Created my Portlet by executing:
   blade create -t mvc-portlet -v 7.3 -p com.liferay.test MVCPortlet7303

etc.
Kind Regards,
Peter

Comment: Hello Peter, 
Thanks for your reply
But the problem is not related to BaseStrutsPortletAction becasue Whenever I created a new portlet mvc with this command (i.e a plain new portlet) " blade create -t mvc-portlet -v 7.0 -p packageName -c className BladePortletAction -b maven " I got the error message and in the console when acceding to the page. maybe it is related to a permission topinc, I don't know exactly...
Console when refreshing:   

[SecurityPortletContainerWrapper:235] Invalid portlet ID /BladePortletAction_WAR_BladePortletAction

Comment: I could not reproduce the role related or the invalid portlet ID error on the liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.3.0-ga1-20200127150653953.tar.gz bundle.

My steps:
blade init -b maven

blade create -t mvc-portlet -v 7.3 -p packageName -c className BladePortletAction -b maven

mvn package

I deployed the built portlet to my running 7.3 portal and added the className portlet to the Welcome page.

Feel free to add to or modify my steps when you are describing what exactly you are doing, and please add those steps here, along with your pom.xml  
  
Cheers :)